# Teams Adaptive Card deep link does not work in MS Teams Preview (beta)

Tags: microsoft-teams

I have a bot that sends messages based on notifications. These notifications still work with [Teams Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fbzl7.png) which contains a deep link to the Teams App in our organization

However, upon entering the beta mode (though our teams app URL's have **not** changed) I'm receiving a far different experience this is the version: [Teams Preview/Beta Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XACrz.png)

Upon clicking my adaptive card teams link I get 'App not found' in the preview / beta mode of teams. When using the classic mode I get the received result which redirects me to my app properly.
[Picture of our adaptive card for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRIkY.png) which contains a teams app link to our app.

[The expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F90LY.png) with Teams classic mode.

[Result I'm receiving](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ya3Lv.png) with the Teams Beta / Preview mode.

I'm hoping someone may have an answer in regards to this issue going forward as it only happens with the beta preview version of MS Teams.

I did find similar post with https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1134485/this-app-cannot-be-found-after-adding-teams-applic however this seems to be adding the applications vs. using a deep link to the app. Not sure if they are 100% related or not but thought I would mention it.

All information is helpful, thanks!

Comment: In the provided issue link, they are experiencing problems when adding the app in Teams. Are you encountering the same issue? You mentioned that when you click on an adaptive card, you receive a message. Could you please share the reproduction steps so that we can attempt to reproduce it from our end?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay.

The app is already added in teams and works flawlessly until beta mode. The steps are as follows: 

1. Send a Teams Deep link to your teams bot.
2. Open the link using the MS Teams client using the preview beta.

You should see an error, the issue only seems to be present when I'm using MS Teams deep links.

Comment: We are also tried the same scenario, but it is working fine from our end.
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/msteams-docs/assets/93527375/90af231d-3caf-4594-94f5-99be5c03a9ff

Microsoft Teams version 23231.413.2355.7555.
The client version is 49/23082000931.

Comment: I appreicate it.

Comment: @Sayali-MSFT do you happen to know if anything structurally changed between the classic vs. the beta in terms of deep linking?

Comment: Just to add on we are using deep links like this: https://teams.microsoft.com/l/entity/<app_id>/<tab_id>?context=%7B%22subEntityId%22%3Anull%7D

I'm more than happy to attach a video of the difference in results for classic vs. beta as well. Hopefully this additional information helps

Comment: Sorry, I ended up finding the solve. It ended up being we were using the external app id. It looks like the new preview does not support using the external app id, so instead we are not using the app id.